# Active Storage - Bug workaround in initializer not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to work around a known issue in Active Storage where the MIME type of a stored file is incorrectly set, without the ability to override it.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32632

This has been addressed in the `master` branch of Rails, however it doesn't appear to be released yet (project is currently using 5.2.0).  Therefor I'm trying to work around the issue using one of the comments provided in the issue:

Within a new initializer (`\config\initializers\active_record_fix.rb`):

```
Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
  # Defeat the ActiveStorage MIME type detection.
  ActiveStorage::Blob.class_eval do
    def extract_content_type(io)
      return content_type if content_type
      Marcel::MimeType.for io, name: filename.to_s, declared_type: content_type
    end
  end
end
```

I'm processing and storing a zip file within a background job using `delayed_jobs`.  The initializer doesn't appear to be getting called.  I have restarted the server.  I'm running the project locally using `heroku local` to process background jobs.

Here is the code storing the file:

```
file.attach(io: File.open(temp_zip_path), filename: 'Download.zip', content_type: 'application/zip')
```

Any ideas why the code above is not working?  Active Storage likes to somewhat randomly decide this ZIP file is a PDF and save the content type as `application\pdf`.  Unrelated, attempting to manually override the `content_type` after attaching doesn't work:

```
file.content_type = 'application/zip'
file.save # No errors, but record doesn't update the content_type
```

Comment: Could you try with `Rails.application.config.to_prepare` in place of `.after_initialize` ?

Comment: This resolved the issue for me, thanks!  If you'd like to post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `Rails.application.config.to_prepare` in place of `after_initialize`  initialization event.

more info :

- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#initialization-events
- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/initialization.html